# Invalid operands to binary % (have float and float)

Tags: c, modulo

Below is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ( )   
{
    float a = 5,b = 2;    
    int c,d;    
    c = a % b;
    d = a/2;    
    printf("%d\n",d);    
    return 0;
}
```

When I try to compile this, I get

> "Invalid operands to binary %"

on the 6th line.  How do I solve this?

Answer (score 5):

```
 c = a % b;
```

You can't use `float` as operand to `%` operator.

Use `fmod` from `math.h` instead .

```
double a=5,b=2,c;
c=fmod(a,b);                 // it returns double
```

Answer (score 1):

As others have already mentioned, you're having issue with the type of the operands for modulo operator. You need to have the operands of type `int` for the modulo operator.

To add some reference, quoting `C11` standard, chapter §6.5.5, *Multiplicative operators*

> [..] The operands of the `%` operator shall
>   have integer type.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use modulo (%) for float args. Maybe you want to do:

```
c = (int) a % (int) b;
```

Answer (score 0):

Modulo operator % is for use with integers, you have used floats.

You could use `fmod(a,b)` and `#include <cmath>`.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure it's on the 6th line? It's more likely to be the line that says

`c = a % b;`

because % only expects integer values, not floating point. You probably need to do a bit of casting if you really want a and b to be floats.